# How to confirm if a package requires any of busybox binaries during run-time?

Tags: busybox

I seek to reduce “busybox” size in my device by removing some of the unwanted binaries.
I have identified such binaries that are not used by my application firmware. But I need to be 100% sure that these binaries are also not required by any of the packages in my device.

My Embedded Linux device includes various packages like the libxml2, termcap, lighttpd, sqlite etc along with Linux kernel.
How should I confirm if these packages require any of the busybox binaries during run-time?

Comment: What exactly is your quetsion?

Comment: `ldd` is a good start.